What is meant by "offers accepted" in Mathjobs portal?
In the Mathjobs portal, some post doctoral positions in mathematics have "offers accepted" written in the post, see:

I am struggling to understand what this means? Because the position seems to still be open and yet it is mentioned that offers are accepted.

Given that the posting provided is for a post-doc starting in August 2024 (a.k.a. last month)*, I think it is safe to assume that they mean exactly that an offer has been made to a candidate and they have accepted the offer (and have probably started the position).
Why the advert on MathJobs is kept open? No clue.
*The statement that "Review of applications will begin on December 15, 2024" is presumably a typo and should say "2023".

I wonder if they tried to reuse their 2023-2024 ad for the 2024-2025 cycle and forgot to update some things.

I am not familiar with the customs on Mathjobs, but it is also possible that someone accepted an offer but agreed to postpone the starting date. This would explain the wording and the fact that the job posting has not been taken off yet, because it is still possible that they will need to fall back to other candidates.
